# How to email to multiple users via x-smtpapi?

Tags: python, sendgrid

I am utilising both [sendgrid-python](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) and [smtpapi-python](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-python) libraries.

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('xx', 'xxx', raise_errors=True)
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.set_subject('yyyy')
with open("../template/s_letter.html", "r") as myfile:
    message.set_html(myfile.read())
message.set_from('xx@xx.org')
message.add_to("xx@xx.com")

header = SMTPAPIHeader()
test_emails = ['xxx@xxx.com', 'xx.xxx@xxx.com']
header.set_tos(test_emails)
message.set_headers(header.json_string())

status, msg = sg.send(message)
```

I am trying to set the `x-smtpapi` header in order to send the same email to multiple users.
However I get the exception.

```
sendgrid.exceptions.SendGridClientError: (400, '{"message": "error", "errors": ["JSON in headers is valid but incompatible"]}')
```

Any idea what I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

The [SendGrid Python Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) in-fact already implements [smptpapi-python](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-python) and passes the methods through to the larger library. So, `message.add_to()` is `header.add_to()`. For this reason, you should *only* need sendgrid-python. Which you may implement as follows:

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('xx', 'xxx', raise_errors=True)
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.set_subject('yyyy')
with open("../template/s_letter.html", "r") as myfile:
    message.set_html(myfile.read())
message.set_from('xx@xx.org')
test_emails = ['xxx@xxx.com', 'xx.xxx@xxx.com']
message.set_tos(test_emails)

status, msg = sg.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late reply but I came across this issue today and after heading up all day I got a solution which I am posting below if anybody lands on this question.

With the message Instance use smtpapi like below:

`message.smtpapi.add_to(test_emails)`